# Where to change default <Super>+<Space> keyboard switch key by a terminal?

Tags: unity, 14.04, shortcut-keys

Since 14.04 default keyboard switch key is <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>

I preparing sample system for clone on hundreds of pc's and want to assign another default keys to switch layout with command line.

I cannot find where this setting is defined in 14.04.

I search `/etc`, `dconf`, `gconf` but cannot find any appropriate configuration in fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04.

Also I want to manage this setting with chef for supporting idempotent configuration in future. So I need to know where it's stored.

Help me to find where it's stored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change this setting by going to *System Settings -> Keyboard*, then go to the *Shortcuts* tab and choose *Typing* on the left. The setting you're looking for is *Switch to next source*.

[image: Changing the keyboard layout switch hotkey in Ubuntu]

This setting is stored by GSettings. I think these settings are stored in `~/.config/dconf/user`, but this is a database file managed by some applications and I would not touch it. Better to use `dconf` to change the setting if you would like to do it via the command line.

You can use `dconf watch /` to see settings that are being changed while you change Ubuntu's system settings via the GUI. E.g., if I run this command, then change the keyboard switcher to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> via the GUI, that command outputs:

```
/org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/switch-input-source
  ['<Super>Tab']
```

So, you could change this switch to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (as an example) via the command line by issuing the command

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/switch-input-source "['<Super>Tab']"
```

Comment: Thank you. This is very complete answer and how-to on the future

Comment: Nevertheless, making the change following these instructions didn't work for me (under Ratpoison rather than Unity).

Comment: @JoeCorneli Obviously, this will not work under Ratpoison. Ratpoison is an entirely different window manager, and does not use any of those `/org/gnome/` settings as Unity does. I am not a user of Ratpoison and can't tell you how to achieve the same thing there - but simply ask the same question for Ratpoison here on AskUbuntu, someone will surely help you out :-)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but i need a little more, then i publish my own complete answer.
This is my complete workaround:

1. First creating an override file:

   `sudo vim /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/60_orgname_custom.gschema.override`

   [org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings]

   switch-input-source=['you_keycode']

   switch-input-source-backward=['you_keycode']
2. I use `<Alt>Shift_L` and `<Alt>Shift_R` in `you_keycode`
3. Recompile schemas:

   `sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/`

Comment: These instructions did not work for me under the Ratpoison WM.