# How to completely disable English(US) keyboard so that switcher doesn't notice it?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I would like to completely disable the English (US) keyboard, so that I can use English (Dvorak) everywhere.  The reason I'm concerned about this is that there's a new hotkey for switching between input methods:

- It is mentioned in this question:
  [Where to change default <Super>+<Space> keyboard switch key by a terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/504019/where-to-change-default-superspace-keyboard-switch-key-by-a-terminal)
- And this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screensaver/+bug/1244548

For my use case, I simply don't want to be bothered with switching (I use Dvorak all the time). I'll note that disabling the hot keys and selecting ONE keyboard seems to work just fine under Unity!  However, changing to a binding other than <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> does not seem to have any effect under Ratpoison. (The binding is actually associated with the keys <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> on my computer, which does not play nicely with Emacs.) I have also removed all other input sources from gnome-control-center, but clearly English (US) is not really completely gone.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that Keyboard Input Method System was not set to "none" inside the Unity Language Support preferences panel.  Changing that made the chooser go away across all window and login managers.